# how to add admin to Devise in Rails/Mongoid user class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, mongoid

I have a class User in Rails using Mongoid and Devise. I can't seem to figure out how to add an Admin role. The How To on the platformtec (Devise) site wants me to run a standard Rails migration, but that's not working because of Mongoid.

Can anyone point me in the correct direction?

Here's my user.rb (minus the modules commented out):

```
class User
    include Mongoid::Document
    # Include default devise modules.
    devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
      :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

    ## Database authenticatable
    field :email,              :type => String, :null => false, :default => ""
    field :encrypted_password, :type => String, :null => false, :default => ""

    ## Recoverable
    field :reset_password_token,   :type => String
    field :reset_password_sent_at, :type => Time

    ## Rememberable
    field :remember_created_at, :type => Time

    ## Trackable
    field :sign_in_count,      :type => Integer, :default => 0
    field :current_sign_in_at, :type => Time
    field :last_sign_in_at,    :type => Time
    field :current_sign_in_ip, :type => String
    field :last_sign_in_ip,    :type => String


    ## Token authenticatable
    # field :authentication_token, :type => String
    field :name
    validates_presence_of :name
    validates_uniqueness_of :name, :email, :case_sensitive => false
    attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me
end
```

Thanks,
Charlie Magee

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need add an `admin` field in Boolean so in your class User add this line :

```
field :admin, :type => Boolean, :default => false
```

it's exactly the same this migration in AR:

```
class AddAdminToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_column :users, :admin, :boolean, :default => false
  end

  def self.down
    remove_column :users, :admin
  end
end
```

After this adding, all method about admin in the devise wiki works fine.

Comment: Duh. Damn. I forgot to capitalize the B in Boolean. I feel like an idiot. Thanks Shingara.

Comment: you need pass a class in type so it's a constant. A constant in Ruby start all the time by a capital letter :)